# AngularJS : ng-show with multiple checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, ng-show

I've used the following solution (accepted answer) to create a new directive for my list of checkboxes: [How can I get angular.js checkboxes with select/unselect all functionality and indeterminate values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648466/how-can-i-get-angular-js-checkboxes-with-select-unselect-all-functionality-and-i) and I want to show the following buttons block when at least one item is selected:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right mrr5" data-ng-show="masterChecked">

    <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove selected</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-download icon-white"></i> Export selected as .csv</button>

</div>
```

As you can see I'm using the 'data-ng-show' attribute with the 'masterChecked' assigned to it, which is set within the controller of the directive based on the status of the 'master':

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="master" data-ng-change="masterChange()">
```

but for some reason whether I check it or not - the buttons do not show up. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Here's the fiddle : [http://jsfiddle.net/scabro/Ahe2X/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/scabro/Ahe2X/19/)

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or plunkr for this. It'll help us help you :)

Comment: @dcodesmith - yes - just added the link in the question above.

Comment: Problem is that `$scope.masterChecked` doesn't belong to `UserController` `$scope`. So it's undefined there. It belongs to the `directives` controller

Comment: It doesn't have to belong to the UserController's scope - it can only reside inside of the directive - check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Ahe2X/27/

Comment: Thanks, I've learnt something new today. I've also forked it for future refence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you are just trying to check the value of another $scope variable ( the one from the directive ) in your main controller

In order to have the same one, you can pass it as another attribute in your directive

I let you check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/Ahe2X/22/

I just modified 3 little points :

First, I created the masterChecked value in the main controller :

```
cmdApp.controller('UserController', function($scope) {
    $scope.masterChecked=false;
    ....
```

we add the masterChecked value in the directive's scope, in order to have the same variable everywhere

```
scope: { checkboxes: '=', masterChecked:"=" },
```

then, we can call the directive with another attribute :

```
<three-state-checkbox checkboxes="users" class="select-all-cb" master-checked="masterChecked">
```

And now, you are manipulating the masterChecked variable from your main controller in your directive, and it works :)

Comment: Thanks @DotDotDot - does it mean I'll have to include the '$scope.masterChecked=false;' within each controller that requires this functionality?

Comment: It depends mostly on your code, the concept here is to tell the directive to manipulate the value already created in the controller, and not a new one which would be created only in the directive's $scope. This will only work if your directive is called somewhere where the controller $scope is accessible ( it's the purpose of `master-checked="masterChecked"`, you tell the directive to use the current controller's $scope.masterChecked ). If it's for another controller, you should consider sharing the masterChecked variable, like in the $rootScope for example (not sure if it's the best solution)

Comment: Well - actually, it appears I don't have to add the '$scope.masterChecked=false;' to the 'UserController' - it works with it being only in the directive :) : http://jsfiddle.net/Ahe2X/27/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/7K52Q/1/).

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right mrr5" data-ng-show="display">

$scope.cbChange = function () {
    $scope.display = !$scope.display;
}
```

Let me know if that works for you or not, I can update it accordingly.

Comment: @dccodesmith - thanks for the example, but it doesn't work when you click on the master checkbox.