# AngularJS ng-checked not changing model value

Tags: angularjs

I have a table of objects with checkbox inputs. If an object's checkbox is checked, the `object.isChecked` value is set to `true`, and if it's unchecked then the value is set to `false`. However, I have a master checkbox that checks/unchecks all the checkboxes in the table. This does not update the `object.isChecked` values however. How would I make the master checkbox change the `object.isChecked` values?

Comment: Can you create a plunker with the example? It's easier to find out =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get angular.js checkboxes with select/unselect all functionality and indeterminate values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648466/how-can-i-get-angular-js-checkboxes-with-select-unselect-all-functionality-and-i)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem must be you trigger checkboxes not inside Angular. If you want Angular magic to work - you must do all your model manipulations inside Angular scope. I've created [a plunker to demonstrate.](http://plnkr.co/edit/47QzyRf5aMeozZVsaE6B?p=preview):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.9.0" data-semver="1.9.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.0.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div data-ng-repeat="object in objects">
      {{object.name}}: <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="object.isChecked">
    </div>
    Master: <input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="triggerAll()">
    {{objects}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
"use strict";

var demo = angular.module("demo", []);

function DemoController($scope) {
  $scope.objects = [
    {
      name : "First",
      isChecked : true
    },
    {
      name : "Second",
      isChecked : false
    }
  ]

  $scope.triggerAll = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.objects, function(value){
      value.isChecked = !value.isChecked;
    })
  }
}
```

Pay attention that triggering all checkboxes is done with `ngClick`, not with usual `onClick` or jQuery handler. This allows Angular to run dirty checks and behave correctly.

Comment: I was already writing a solution similar to this, but I had hoped there was a built in angular way of doing it. Thank you.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to bind several bools to one checkbox.