# How to check all checkbox in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am trying to check all `checkboxes` in angular's way.

I have the following codes:

```
 <div>
     <div class="checkbox">
          <input ng-click="checkAll =! checkAll" type="checkbox"/> check all
     </div>
     <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"/> {{item.title}}
     </div>
</div>
```

I was able to check all `checkboxes` when I click the `check all`, however, if I check and uncheck the individual `checkbox`, the `check all` doesn't seem to applied that individual `checkbox` anymore. Can anyone help me about this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648466/how-can-i-get-angular-js-checkboxes-with-select-unselect-all-functionality-and-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Revised answer:**

An alternative approach to the other answer using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
app.directive('myCheckBox', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      checkAll: '=',
    },
    template: '<input check-all="checkAll" type="checkbox" ng-model="check"/>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('checkAll', function(newVal){
        scope.check = newVal;
      })
    },

  }
})
```

I passed the parent scope's `checkAll` to the new directive's scope and added a watcher for it.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vIbRpwrfp1LEefm8kYYt?p=preview)

---

**Old answer:**

You can use `$parent` (will access the scope's parent scope):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checkAll"/> {{item.title}}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FIpqkoaO1Qlje30w1xMF?p=preview)

And you should have `checkAll` as `ng-model` for the main checkbox as well, rather than as a click event.

The problem you were having is due to [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) creating a scope for each repetition.

Comment: Your demo doesn't work.  Every checkbox does the same thing (selects/deselects all checkboxes).  Only "check all" should check all the boxes.  a, b, and c should work independently.

Comment: @Jerrad thought that's what he wanted, now I see I misread. On it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show what your `$scope.items` looks like.  If it is an array of primitives, then that's a problem.  `ng-repeat` will create a new scope for each item that inherits from the parent scope.  The problem is that for primitives, it just makes a copy of the value, and you lose the two-way binding.  Instead, make your items an array of objects, like this:

```
$scope.items = [
  {name: 'a', checked: false}, 
  {name: 'b', checked: false}, 
  {name: 'c', checked: false}
];
```

You should also have a separate variable for the "Check All" checkbox.

```
$scope.checkAll = false;
```

Now make a function to loop through all the items and set the `checked` property:

```
$scope.checkAllBoxes = function(){
    $scope.checkAll = !$scope.checkAll;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
      item.checked = $scope.checkAll;
    })
}
```

Bind it all up like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkAllBoxes()" /> check all
</div>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"/> {{item.name}}
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YiCK9VolWAONIrAbxpaN?p=preview)