# Problem with select all tri-state checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes - two parents and each parent has 5 childs.
The parents should have 3 states (checked,unchecked,indeterminate).
Right now, my code is working BUT I'm trying to add a 'select all' checkbox , 
which will select the two parents and all their childs.

What I tried to do is adding one more label above:

```
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-indeterminate-checkbox data-child- 
     list="model.people" data-property="eaten" data-ng- 
     model="model.allEaten"> All eaten
    </label>
```

but it's not working - the checkbox is not acting as expected.

Full code:
    http://jsfiddle.net/wnjze03h/210/

HTML:

```js
var app = angular.module('combo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        allEaten: false,
        people: [
            {
                name: "Bob",
                fruits: [
                    { type: 'Apple', eaten: false },
                    { type: 'Banana', eaten: false },
                    { type: 'Pear', eaten: true },
                    { type: 'Tomato', eaten: false },
                    { type: 'Grapefruit', eaten: true },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Joe",
                fruits: [
                    { type: 'Apple', eaten: true },
                    { type: 'Banana', eaten: true },
                    { type: 'Pear', eaten: true },
                    { type: 'Tomato', eaten: true },
                    { type: 'Grapefruit', eaten: true },
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
}]);

/**
 * Directive for an indeterminate (tri-state) checkbox.
 * Based on the examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648466/how-can-i-get-angular-js-checkboxes-with-select-unselect-all-functionality-and-i
 */
app.directive('indeterminateCheckbox', [function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var childList = attrs.childList;
            var property = attrs.property;
   
   // Bind the onChange event to update children
   element.bind('change', function() {
    scope.$apply(function () {
     var isChecked = element.prop('checked');
     
     // Set each child's selected property to the checkbox's checked property
     angular.forEach(scope.$eval(childList), function(child) {
      child[property] = isChecked;
     });
    });
   });
   
   // Watch the children for changes
   scope.$watch(childList, function(newValue) {
    var hasChecked = false;
    var hasUnchecked = false;
    
    // Loop through the children
    angular.forEach(newValue, function(child) {
     if (child[property]) {
      hasChecked = true;
     } else {
      hasUnchecked = true;
     }
    });
    
    // Determine which state to put the checkbox in
    if (hasChecked && hasUnchecked) {
     element.prop('checked', false);
     element.prop('indeterminate', true);
                    if (modelCtrl) {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(false);
                    }
    } else {
     element.prop('checked', hasChecked);
     element.prop('indeterminate', false);
                    if (modelCtrl) {
         modelCtrl.$setViewValue(hasChecked);
                    }
    }
   }, true);
  }
 };
}]);
```

```css
.person {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.child-list {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-indeterminate-checkbox data-child-list="model.people.allEaten" data-property="eaten" data-ng-model="model.allEaten"> All eaten
    </label>
<div data-ng-repeat="person in model.people" class="person">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-indeterminate-checkbox data-child-list="person.fruits" data-property="eaten" data-ng-model="person.allEaten"> {{person.name}} [All eaten: {{person.allEaten}}]
    </label>
    <div data-ng-repeat="fruit in person.fruits" class="child-list">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="fruit.eaten"> {{fruit.type}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your code here? And what exactly do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: not working - the checkbox is not connected to the parents and childs. nothing happen when you check/uncheck the 'ALL EATEN'

Comment: And still, what have you tried to solve this? Does the click trigger any JS code? Does that code select the proper checkboxes?

Comment: It should not trigger any function , it should watch the children of that input and according to those changes - it should automatically get checked,unchecked

Answer (score 1):

remove your directive and add following html

```
<label>
    <input style="-webkit-appearance:checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.allEaten" ng-click="selectAllEaten(model.allEaten)"> 
     allEaten {{model.allEaten}}
</label>
<div ng-repeat="person in model.people">
    <label>
        <input style="-webkit-appearance:checkbox" ng-checked="person.selected" type="checkbox" ng-model="person.selected" ng-click="selectByPerson(person)">
        {{person.name}}
    </label>
    <div ng-repeat="fruit in person.fruits" style="margin-left:20px;">
        <label>
            <input style="-webkit-appearance:checkbox" ng-checked="fruit.selected" type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.eaten">
            {{fruit.type}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.selectAllEaten = function (x) {
    if (x) {
        $scope.model.people.forEach(function (item) {
            item.selected = true;
            item.fruits.forEach(function (fruit) { fruit.selected = true; });
        });
    } else {
        $scope.model.people.forEach(function (item) {
            item.selected = false;
            item.fruits.forEach(function (fruit) { fruit.selected = false; });
        });
    }
}

$scope.selectByPerson = function(x){        
    if (x.selected) {
        x.fruits.forEach(function (fruit) { fruit.selected = true; });
    }else{
        x.fruits.forEach(function (fruit) { fruit.selected = false; });
    }
}
```

do further validations such as checking parent if all child checked , etc